# When using Neural Architecture Search, how are the hyper-parameters chosen?

Tags: neural-networks, hyper-parameters, neuroevolution, neural-architecture-search

I have read a lot about NAS, but I still do not understand one concept: When setting up a neural network, hyperparameters (such as the learning rate, dropout rate, batch size, filter size, etc.) need to be set up.

In NAS, only the best architecture is decided, e.g. how many layers and neurons. But what about the hyperparameters? Are they randomly chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clearly stated (it's not stated **at all** on Wikipedia), but, after a bit of searching, I found an answer [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-architecture-search-limitations-and-extensions-8141bec7681f) about a third of the way down the page:

> The best performing architecture observed during the training of the controller is taken, and **a grid search is performed over some basic hyperparameters such as learning rate and weight decay** in order to achieve near STOTA (state of the art) performance.

So, as a direct answer: The norm; [A grid search](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/an-introduction-to-grid-search-ff57adcc0998).